# Monteverdi - Orfeo Toolbox: OTB Applications browser empty

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Orfeo Toolbox using the binaries[¹]

I loaded Monteverdi and clicked on View -> OTB Applications browser but the Menus is empty:

[image]

[¹] https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/download/

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a 64 bits Linux system?  Binary has been built for this architecture.

Comment: yes I do have a 64 bit system

Answer (score 1):

In the View section, click on "OTB Applications browser".

Applications are not loaded automattically at startup as it can slow a bit the software at startup. It should add a new widget to the application with the list of all available applications.

Not that there is no need to be admin to run the OTB standalone pakage

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Check the screenshot I posted, I clicked on View and activated OTB-Applications browser.

Comment: you need to run the launcher script monteverdi.sh at the root of the binary package. It will set all paths and launch monteverdi with all applications.  The monteverdi.sh bash script is located in  OTB-contrib-6.0.0-Linux64/ (not in the bin directory). You'll find also more information in the README inside the package.

Answer (score -1):

Run it with **Administrator previlages**, It will work!

Comment: I tried to run it as sudo ./monteverdi but it is still blank